# Why Elixir can't print Unicode String after splitting it?

Tags: unicode, elixir

This works: `"ы д" |> IO.puts`

But this is not: `"ы д" |> String.split(~r/[^а-я]+/) |> hd |> IO.puts`

```
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    (stdlib) :io.put_chars(#PID<0.26.0>, :unicode, [<<209>>, 10])
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex in Elixir are not Unicode codepoint based by default. You need to pass the [`u` modifier](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Regex.html) to enable matching on Unicode codepoints:

```
iex(1)> "ы д" |> String.split(~r/[^а-я]+/u)
["ы", "д"]
iex(2)> "ы д" |> String.split(~r/[^а-я]+/u) |> hd
"ы"
```

Without `u`, the return values are not UTF-8:

```
iex(1)> "ы д" |> String.split(~r/[^а-я]+/)
[<<209>>, "д"]
```